# iOS view change with gesture problem

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

here is my problem: In mainviewcontroller I added to swipe down gesture to switch down another view, but inside  other views added to mainviewcontroller with swipe down gesture opens that specific view. However, I dont want swipe down gesture in other views rather than main view.

```
//---gesture recognizer

- (IBAction) handleSwipes:(UIGestureRecognizer *) sender {
    UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection direction = [(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender direction];

    if (direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown) {
        shakeController = [[ShakeViewController alloc] 
                           initWithNibName:@"ShakeViewController" bundle:nil];

        CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
        transition.duration = 0.5;

        transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

        transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;

        transition.delegate = self;

        // Next add it to the containerView's layer. This will perform the transition based on how we change its contents.
        [self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

        [self.view addSubview:shakeController.view];

    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //gesture recognizer
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                              initWithTarget:self
                                              action:@selector(handleSwipes:)];
    swipeGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];

    [swipeGesture release];
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should adopt the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol and implement `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` method to signal whether the gesture recognizer should respond or not.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    for ( UIView *subview in self.view.subviews ) {
        CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:subview];
        UIView *hitView = [subview hitTest:point withEvent:nil];
        if ( hitView != nil ) {
            return NO; // Touching one of the subviews so we will not accept the gesture.
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I did this, but still in other subviews I have added to mainView with swipe down gesture, directed to shakeControll view???

Comment: I didn't get you here. Are you still able to swipe down on subviews? What is this `shakeControll`?

Comment: Ok, I will try to clarify my problem. I have 4 view controller, mainController, subMainController(named shakeController and want to be directed to this view with swipe down gesture) and there is 2 other views added to mainController (directed to them via button click). In main view swipe down gesture works properly and directed to submainView, but what I dont want is swipe down gesture also work in other 2 views and direct me to that submainview. Hope the problem is clear now, thanks

Comment: [`This`](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22783696/SwipeDown.zip) is a small example which I have created. While it doesn't load a new view, it prints `Swiped` on the console. Here I am unable to trigger the swipe gesture on a subview.

Comment: Ok, I finally be able to make it work with your code. Added swipeGesture.delegate = self; too :) Thanks